# label assignment from lookup dictionary keys and value in Python

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

Given a list

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

I would like to label at each of the list position as below

```
['fir', 'fir', 'sec', 'fir', 'fir', 'fir', 'thr', 'sec', 'fou', 'fou', 'fou', 'thr', 'sec', 'fou']
```

with respect to a lookup dictionary `m`

```
m={ "fir": [0,1,3,4,5],
        "sec": [2,7,12],
        "thr": [6,11],
        "fou": [8,9,10,13]}
```

Let take for example the first three position.

From the dict `m`, the position `0` and `1` fell under the key `fir`. Whereas, the third position (e.g., 2) is under the key `sec`.

Hence, the list for the three are ['fir', 'fir', 'sec'].

To achieve the above objective, the following is drafted

```
m={ "fir": [0,1,3,4,5],
        "sec": [2,7,12],
        "thr": [6,11],
        "fou": [8,9,10,13]}

all_key=m.keys()
all_opt=[]
for idx in range (sum(len(v) for v in m.values())):
  for nkey in all_key:
    if idx in m[nkey]:
      all_opt.append(nkey)
      break
```

which produced

```
opt=['fir', 'fir', 'sec', 'fir', 'fir', 'fir', 'thr', 'sec', 'fou', 'fou', 'fou', 'thr', 'sec', 'fou']
```

I wonder whether there is better alternative than the nested for-loop?

Comment: It might be more efficient overall to invert `m` to map index numbers to words, then use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invert the mapping dictionary so that mapping would be:

- `valuei ⟶ labelj` instead of `label ⟶ [value0...valuen]`

You can invert the dictionary using dict comprehension

```
inv_m = {v: k for k, lst in m.items() for v in lst}
print(inv_m)
# {0: 'fir', 1: 'fir', 3: 'fir', 4: 'fir', 5: 'fir', 2: 'sec',
#  7: 'sec', 12: 'sec', 6: 'thr', 11: 'thr', 8: 'fou', 9: 'fou',
#  10: 'fou', 13: 'fou'}
```

Now, iterate over the given list and map each value to its corresponding label.

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
out = [inv_m[v] for v in lst]
print(out)
# ['fir', 'fir', 'sec', 'fir', 'fir', 'fir', 'thr', 'sec', 'fou',
#  'fou', 'fou', 'thr', 'sec', 'fou']
```

Comment: For that data, it takes about half as much time as the OP's but twice as much time as the other answer's.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, the results of my timeit as analogous with yours on larger data(10,000 elements) too. My bad I assumed the values in the list may not be indices. Example, `lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']; m = {"fir": ["a", "b"], "sec": ["c"]}`.

Comment: @KellyBundy But if this is called a 1000 times, we only need to build `inv_m` only once, for the rest 999 times list is comp is enough unless new labels are added. After changing `out = [inv_m[v] ...]` to `list(map(inv_m.get, lst))` it's much faster. For the 1st run my solution including building `inv_m` and `list(map(...))` is almost slower by 2 times than the other answer. For rest 999 times I don't need to build inv_m so I timed my `list(map(...))` against his code. `list(map(...))` is faster but the difference is only about 60 µs on an avg.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to compare only a part of your process with their whole process. Why would you need to build `inv_m` only once? As soon as `m` changes, `inv_m` must change as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy That what's I metioned in my comments. If `m` doesn't why would you build it every single time? If `m` changes constantly then we build it everytime.

Comment: @KellyBundy To be clear. For benchmarking we should compare whole process with the other answer. But what I meant to say is if this function is called a 1000 times in a scripts where if `m` doesn't change then there's no need tk build `inv_m`.

Comment: I think if `m` doesn't change, then there's no need to rebuild `out`, either. While the OP does say "Given a list", that list doesn't actually seem to be given. Their `m` seems to be the only actual input. Otherwise they'd use that list in their code, they wouldn't compute the sum of lengths, and their `for idx in range` would be wrong.

Comment: @KellyBundy I thought `m` would be a constant and the OP has a list to be mapped. I assumed that list can be anything but my bad they are indices. I thought he would apply mapping on lists that they would receive. That's the reason why I was commenting there's no need to rebuild `inv_m`. I'm happy to delete the answer as I have misread the question but it's accepted answer there's no option to delete it unless they accept the other answer.

Comment: Well, it might still be me who's misinterpreting, or the next person with this problem seeking a solution might have the version you interpreted it as, so I wouldn't delete.

Answer (score 1):

Create a fixed size list and fill it by putting labels to corresponding indexes:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
m = { 
    "fir": [0,1,3,4,5],
    "sec": [2,7,12],
    "thr": [6,11],
    "fou": [8,9,10,13]
}

label_lst = [''] * len(lst)
for label, idxs in m.items():
    for idx in idxs:    
        label_lst[idx] = label

print(label_lst)
```

**Output**

```
['fir', 'fir', 'sec', 'fir', 'fir', 'fir', 'thr', 'sec', 'fou', 'fou', 'fou', 'thr', 'sec', 'fou']
```

Comment: That's the straightforward answer and should be the top one. Benchmark might be good (especially since the question *is* tagged with `performance`).